# Find hashtag of any language and replace with link in string

Tags: node.js, mongodb, hashtag, unicode-string, find-replace

Find #hashtag from string in node js for e.g:

my String is:
`string = "I Love #भारत #ভারত #ભારત #ਭਾਰਤ #ଭାରତ #இந்தியா #ഇന്ത്യ #ಭಾರತ #భారత #india and the whole country."`

Output:
`hashtag = ["भारत", "ভারত", "ભારત", "ਭਾਰਤ", "ଭାରତ", "இந்தியா", "ഇന്ത്യ", "ಭಾರತ", "భారత", "india"]`

also i need to replace string in node js for e.g.

Input
`String = "I Love #भारत #ভারত #ભારત #ਭਾਰਤ #ଭାରତ #இந்தியா #ഇന്ത്യ #ಭಾರತ #భారత #india and the whole country.";`

Output
`String = "I Love <a href='http://hostname/hashtag/भारत' target='_blank'>#भारत</a> <a href='http://hostname/hashtag/ভারত' target='_blank'>#ভারত</a> <a href='http://hostname/hashtag/ભારત' target='_blank'>#ભારત</a> <a href='http://hostname/hashtag/ਭਾਰਤ' target='_blank'>#ਭਾਰਤ</a> <a href='http://hostname/hashtag/ଭାରତ' target='_blank'>#ଭାରତ</a> <a href='http://hostname/hashtag/இந்தியா' target='_blank'>#இந்தியா</a> <a href='http://hostname/hashtag/ഇന്ത്യ' target='_blank'>#ഇന്ത്യ</a> <a href='http://hostname/hashtag/ಭಾರತ' target='_blank'>#ಭಾರತ</a> <a href='http://hostname/hashtag/భారత' target='_blank'>#భారత</a> <a href='http://hostname/hashtag/india' target='_blank'>#india</a> and the whole country.";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your string:

```
const str= "I Love #भारत #ভারত #ભારત #ਭਾਰਤ #ଭାରତ #இந்தியா #ഇന്ത്യ #ಭಾರತ #భారత #india and the whole country.";
```

> To Match hashtags from string.

you can use `match` method of string. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) is the reference.

```
str.match(/(#\S*)/g);
```

Your code becomes:

```js
const str = "I Love #भारत #ভারত #ભારત #ਭਾਰਤ #ଭାରତ #இந்தியா #ഇന്ത്യ #ಭಾರತ #భారత #india and the whole country.";

const result = str.match(/(#\S*)/g).map(hash=>hash.substr(1));

console.log(result);
```

> To replace hashtags with links.

For the hashtag replacement, you can use the same regex with `replace` method of the string.

Here is your code:

```js
const str = "I Love #भारत #ভারত #ભારત #ਭਾਰਤ #ଭାରତ #இந்தியா #ഇന്ത്യ #ಭಾರತ #భారత #india and the whole country.";


const result = str.replace(/(#\S*)/g, (hashtag) => {
  const hash=hashtag.substr(1);
  return `<a href='http://hostname/hashtag/${hash}' target='_blank'>${hash}</a>`
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Please recheck my question again.

Answer (score 0):

```
var main = "I Love #भारत #ভারত #ભારત #ਭਾਰਤ #ଭାରତ #இந்தியா #ഇന്ത്യ #ಭಾರತ #భారత #india and the whole country."

var myString = main.match(/(#\S*)/g);

console.log(myString);
```

Example: https://repl.it/repls/ChartreuseElectronicTransformation

Comment: Please recheck my question again.

Comment: @LaxmikantDange Am not copy your code i just refer this link https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-match/